# How set place holder if data source doesn't have items

Tags: kendo-ui

I have drop down and empty dataSource.

I need set place holder even if data source is empty

example: http://jsfiddle.net/dude_jsfiddle/C8tBa/1/

It's bug kendoui?

version kendo `Q1 2013 (version 2013.1.319)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add:

```
set autoBind false
```